# Uploadify: transparency in images becoming black

Tags: jquery, cakephp, uploadify

I'm running into a problem using the jQuery Uploadify plugin in my cakePHP application.

It all works well apart from an issue I'm getting when I upload an image with transparency. Whenever I upload an image with transparency, the transparent areas of the image are stored as black.

I suspect this may be caused by the Uploadify plugin not loading the alpha channel of the image properly, but I can't be sure.

Comment: hm I think I have to change the core code of the uploadify plugin.

by the way Thanks for the reply..

Cheers...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did that, and whether or not it is actually a bug in the plugin, or if it was something that you overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contribution.

I have resolved the issue I have to change the bit of code inside the resize function of image component that I am using to upload image.

I have to put some code before :

`imagecopyresampled($imgDes, $imgSrc, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $trueWidth, $trueHeight);`

And the New code is as below :

```
        if($fileType == 'png' || $fileType == 'gif') {
        imagealphablending($imgDes, false);
        imagesavealpha($imgDes,true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($imgDes, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($imgDes, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
    }
```

Put this New code in below function of image component :

```
function resizeImg($imgName, $size, $fileName)
```